# Chromium not rendering properly on some webpages

Tags: lubuntu, chromium

For some reason, Chromium doesn't seem to load certain parts of some webpages. I've been trying to fix it but to no avail. I was hoping someone knew how to fix this issue.

I'm using Lubuntu 22.04 LTS. Below is the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

**EDIT:**

- Tried doing `sudo fc-cache -f -v` still got nothing.
- Updated the system to latest, same result.

Comment: Make sure your system is fully updated.

Comment: This looks like a "missing font" issue. Let's start by forcing a refresh of the font cache. Run this in Terminal: `sudo fc-cache -f -v`. If it solves the problem, great. If it doesn't, please [edit] your question to let us know whether you've added/removed fonts recently.